# How can I make paths connect to my rides?

Tags: rollercoaster-tycoon-3

Whenever I place a ride, it gets placed on a small platform only slightly above the ground, and any paths I place to connect to the entrance/exit won't connect to it. This is all on completely flat ground. I can't get stairs or sloped paths to connect to them either. Using shift to adjust height does also not fix this issue. The land I'm placing it on is completely flat.

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Update: I took some screenshots of this problem, since I'm still having it.

[image: A Wild Mouse rollercoaster with the issue described]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the flatten terrain tool for rides and scenery. It's in terrain tools. It might be called flatten terrain in increments or something, also.

Answer (score 2):

I had that happen to me the only thing i could do is lower the ground under the ride and then put the ride in place that should help fix the problem, i will do a little more research to come up with a few different solutions

Answer (score 2):

While placing a ride you can hold SHIFT (or alt, it has been a while) and scroll or slide the mouse to raise or lower you ride from the ground. However the problem might be that your terrain is not flat and the ride gets placed on the highest tile which means the rest of the ride floats above the lower tiles. There is a flatten tool in the terrain edit panel.

You can raise your paths by one and two steps if you just hold the mouse and dragging up or down when placing a path at the edge of a tile. This way you can always hook up your rides.

Comment: Thanks for down-voting the best answer from a RCT pro ;)

Answer (score 1):

Easy solution! What others have suggested work but are way more difficult. Go into the terrain editor, then go to the top option, then go to the top far left option which raises individual tiles. Then you can raise up only half of the tile in front of the entrance to build a walkable surface to connect to a path.

Answer (score -3):

What I Did Was Is I Went To The Spade Thing And Made the 1 square in front on the entrance and exit and made them to square the same height as the entrance and exit and then go to paths and make the path go in the air and make it go back down.